# Converting mathematical expressions to Matlab scripts

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have some equations and want to code them in Matlab. These are parts of equality constraints for an optimization problem. It's GAMS script and mathematical equation is known for me. These terms are as follows:

[image]

```
GAMS:
p1_bal(ib)  ..      (pgn1(ib)-pdn1(ib)) =e= v1(ib)*sum(ib1, ybus1_m(ib,ib1)*v1(ib1)*cos(ybus1_a(ib,ib1)+a1(ib1)-a1(ib)));
q1_bal(ib)  ..      (qgn1(ib)-qdn1(ib)) =e= -v1(ib)*sum(ib1, ybus1_m(ib,ib1)*v1(ib1)*sin(ybus1_a(ib,ib1)+a1(ib1)-a1(ib)));
```

So I have tried to write it's `Matlab` scrip based on above, But I am not sure if its true. Please check these `Matlab` scrip and tell me if they are in accordance with its mathematical or `GAMS` scripts.

```
p_bal  =  -(pgn-pdn)+v_mt.*((Ybus_m.*cos(Delta)*v_mt)); 
q_bal  =   -(qgn-qdn)+v_mt.*((Ybus_m.*sin(Delta))*v_mt);
```

where `pgn,pdn,qgn,qdn,v_mt` are `(n x 1)` vectors `Ybus_m and Delta` are `(n x n)` matrices. `Delta` is also defined as :

```
Delta =bsxfun(@minus,v_at(:),v_at(:).')-Ybus_a;   
%v_at(:)=d{n},v_at(:)'=d{h},Ybus_a=tet{n,h}
```

Comment: So, whats the problem?

Comment: Well, the question was not clear. I've edited the question to make it more clear for viewers. Anyway, I wanted to say that Mathematical and GAMS scripts for these equations are know. I have tried to re-write them in matlab, but still I am not so sure if they are in accordance with its mathematical or gams version. What do you think @AnderBiguri

Comment: Have you tried comparing the results? Do they give the same number?

Comment: I cannot compare it with GAMS results, Because I don't have its software and also don't know about its scripting. @AnderBiguri